# How overflow:hidden helps div grow in the html css below?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id='container' >

   <div id='content' > </div>
   <div id='rightPane' > </div>

</div>
```

In the structure above content and rightPane are childs of container div. They contain the content and they expand in height with the growing content but the container div does'nt expand with it. I want to know the reason for it. Also i want to know when i apply overflow:hidden to container it starts expanding with the content in child divs. What happens when we apply overflow:hidden to the container parent div.

Comment: If you are use overflow:hidden; it will expand and also if u r used float:left; It also expand with children div. float:left; is giving more complexity of inner part. So always use overflow:hidden; and display:block; for parent div it will give less complexity.

Comment: If you are use overflow:hidden; it will expand and also if u r used float:left; It also expand with children div. float:left; is giving more complexity of inner part. So always use overflow:hidden; and display:block; for parent div it will give less complexity.

Comment: It's a method to clear floats element by there parent check this for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740347/clearing-nested-floats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will be helpfull for you..

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html